# Inject script globally in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have the following bit of code in my global `index.js` file in React:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'assets/js/custom.js';
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This injects a script tag to the body of the dom. This doesn't quite work as expected, it appends the file but it doesn't trigger any of the jQuery code in the file.

However if I put the exact same script in a `componentDidMount` function of one of my components it works fine.

I don't want to add this to each and every component, How can I do this globally?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression )

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Where do I place that?

Comment: google it, http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Yeah I know what it is but how would I use it in my context?

Comment: Couldn't you make it part of the vendor file, and let your bundler take care of it? Or to make it part of the entry file for your code?